How can I turn date intervals given in columns and extract the volumes per hour in the time interval for muiltiple overlapping periods?
I have the following df:
Start_Date   End_Date  Relevant  Volume   
2024-10-01 2024-12-31     False  0.000000   
2025-01-01 2025-03-31      True  0.097989   
2025-04-01 2025-06-30      True -0.014449   
2025-01-01 2025-12-31      True  0.195327   
2026-01-01 2026-12-31     False  0.000000   

I need an hourly index starting/ending at the first/last dates, where Relevant == True. I do this as follows:
    relevant_df = df[df['Relevant']]    
    earliest_start = relevant_df['Start_Date'].min()
    latest_end = relevant_df['End_Date'].max()
    # Create DateTime index
    date_range = pd.date_range(start=earliest_start, end=latest_end, freq='H')
    aggregated_volumes = pd.Series(index=date_range, dtype=float)

Now, how can I take the Volume per periode and add them together so that, in this ex, the first three months of 2025, the volume per hour equals 0.097989 + 0.195327 second quarter -0.014449 + 0.195327 etc..

Since your intervals are overlapping, I believe there is no direct way to index your values.
You can however create a NxM numpy array (N: number of rows, M: number of True rows) and sum:
# ensure datetime
relevant_df[['Start_Date', 'End_Date']] = relevant_df[['Start_Date', 'End_Date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# compute a mask of the values between start/end
idx = date_range.to_numpy()[:, None]
m1 = idx>=relevant_df['Start_Date'].to_numpy()
m2 = idx<relevant_df['End_Date'].to_numpy()

# broadcast the values, sum, convert to Series
out = pd.Series(np.nansum(np.where(m1&m2, relevant_df['Volume'].to_numpy(), np.nan), axis=1),
                index=date_range)

Output:
2025-01-01 00:00:00    0.293316
2025-01-01 01:00:00    0.293316
2025-01-01 02:00:00    0.293316
2025-01-01 03:00:00    0.293316
2025-01-01 04:00:00    0.293316
                         ...   
2025-12-30 20:00:00    0.195327
2025-12-30 21:00:00    0.195327
2025-12-30 22:00:00    0.195327
2025-12-30 23:00:00    0.195327
2025-12-31 00:00:00    0.000000
Freq: h, Length: 8737, dtype: float64

Alternatively, if you have sparse intervals relative to the full range:
out = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(v, index=pd.date_range(s, e, inclusive='left', freq='h'))
                    for s,e,v in zip(relevant_df['Start_Date'],
                                     relevant_df['End_Date'],
                                     relevant_df['Volume']
                                    )]).sum()

Output:
2025-01-01 00:00:00    0.293316
2025-01-01 01:00:00    0.293316
2025-01-01 02:00:00    0.293316
2025-01-01 03:00:00    0.293316
2025-01-01 04:00:00    0.293316
                         ...   
2025-12-30 19:00:00    0.195327
2025-12-30 20:00:00    0.195327
2025-12-30 21:00:00    0.195327
2025-12-30 22:00:00    0.195327
2025-12-30 23:00:00    0.195327
Freq: h, Length: 8736, dtype: float64

Visual output:


The last 23 hours are not filled with volumes, even after changing the above to: latest_end = relevant_base['End_Date'].max() + pd.DateOffset(hours=23). The last 23 rows are all zero,, any idea how to fix this?

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix, csc_matrix, csr_matrix


data = {
    'Start_Date': ['2024-10-01', '2025-01-01', '2025-04-01', '2025-01-01', '2026-01-01'],
    'End_Date': ['2024-12-31', '2025-03-31', '2025-06-30', '2025-12-31', '2026-12-31'],
    'Relevant': [False, True, True, True, False],
    'Volume': [0.0, 0.097989, -0.014449, 0.195327, 0.0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Ensure datetime format
df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'])
df['End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Date'])
print(df)


  Start_Date   End_Date  Relevant    Volume
0 2024-10-01 2024-12-31     False  0.000000
1 2025-01-01 2025-03-31      True  0.097989
2 2025-04-01 2025-06-30      True -0.014449
3 2025-01-01 2025-12-31      True  0.195327
4 2026-01-01 2026-12-31     False  0.000000

# Filter rows where Relevant == True
relevant_df = df[df['Relevant']]
print(relevant_df)

  Start_Date   End_Date  Relevant    Volume
1 2025-01-01 2025-03-31      True  0.097989
2 2025-04-01 2025-06-30      True -0.014449
3 2025-01-01 2025-12-31      True  0.195327

#generate hourly date range
date_range = pd.date_range(start= relevant_df['Start_Date'].min(), 
                           end =relevant_df['Start_Date'].max() ,freq = 'h')

print(date_range.to_series())

2025-01-01 00:00:00   2025-01-01 00:00:00
2025-01-01 01:00:00   2025-01-01 01:00:00
2025-01-01 02:00:00   2025-01-01 02:00:00
2025-01-01 03:00:00   2025-01-01 03:00:00
2025-01-01 04:00:00   2025-01-01 04:00:00
                              ...        
2025-03-31 20:00:00   2025-03-31 20:00:00
2025-03-31 21:00:00   2025-03-31 21:00:00
2025-03-31 22:00:00   2025-03-31 22:00:00
2025-03-31 23:00:00   2025-03-31 23:00:00
2025-04-01 00:00:00   2025-04-01 00:00:00
Freq: h, Length: 2161, dtype: datetime64[ns]

date_range_length = len(date_range)
#print(date_range_length)#2161


rows : This array defines which row each element in the data belongs to.
It is created by repeating the indices of relevant entries (len(relevant_df))
date_range_length times.

cols : This array defines which column each element in the data belongs to.
get the values wrt first_non_null_indices


rows = np.repeat(np.arange(len(relevant_df)), len(date_range))
#print(rows)#[0 0 0 ... 2 2 2]
cols = np.tile(np.arange(len(date_range)), len(relevant_df))
#print(cols)#[   0    1    2 ... 2158 2159 2160]

relevant_volume_data = relevant_df['Volume'].values.repeat(len(date_range))

relevant_volume_data : 
[0.097989 0.097989 0.097989 ... 0.195327 0.195327 0.195327]


`np.searchsorted is used for finding the insertion points in a sorted array. It quickly determines where each Start_Date and End_Date would fit within the date_range.


start_indices = np.searchsorted(date_range, relevant_df['Start_Date'].values)
end_indices = np.searchsorted(date_range, relevant_df['End_Date'].values)


Why not (cols <= end_indices[rows]) instead of (cols < end_indices[rows]) ?

-Ans :

If start_indices and end_indices happen to have duplicate values
the (cols < end_indices[rows]) condition might exclude
the last element for that entry compared to (cols <= end_indices[rows])

mask = (cols >= start_indices[rows]) & (cols < end_indices[rows])
rows_masked,cols_masked,relevant_volume_data_masked = rows[mask], cols[mask], relevant_volume_data[mask]

csr_sparse_matrix = csr_matrix( (relevant_volume_data_masked, (rows_masked,cols_masked)),

shape =  (len(relevant_df), len(date_range) )
) 

  (0, 0)    0.097989
  (0, 1)    0.097989
  (0, 2)    0.097989
  (0, 14)    0.097989
  (0, 15)    0.097989
  (0, 21)    0.097989
  (0, 22)    0.097989
  (0, 23)    0.097989
  (0, 24)    0.097989
  :    :
  (2, 2136)    0.195327
  (2, 2137)    0.195327
  (2, 2138)    0.195327
  (2, 2139)    0.195327
  (2, 2140)    0.195327
  (2, 2159)    0.195327
  (2, 2160)    0.195327

summed_volumes = np.array(csr_sparse_matrix.sum(axis=0)).flatten()

summed_volumes:
[0.293316 0.293316 0.293316 ... 0.195327 0.195327 0.180878]

res = pd.Series(summed_volumes,index = date_range)
print(res)

2025-01-01 00:00:00    0.293316
2025-01-01 01:00:00    0.293316
2025-01-01 02:00:00    0.293316
2025-01-01 03:00:00    0.293316
2025-01-01 04:00:00    0.293316
                         ...   
2025-03-31 20:00:00    0.195327
2025-03-31 21:00:00    0.195327
2025-03-31 22:00:00    0.195327
2025-03-31 23:00:00    0.195327
2025-04-01 00:00:00    0.180878
Freq: h, Length: 2161, dtype: float64


Full Code :


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix, csc_matrix, csr_matrix


data = {
    'Start_Date': ['2024-10-01', '2025-01-01', '2025-04-01', '2025-01-01', '2026-01-01'],
    'End_Date': ['2024-12-31', '2025-03-31', '2025-06-30', '2025-12-31', '2026-12-31'],
    'Relevant': [False, True, True, True, False],
    'Volume': [0.0, 0.097989, -0.014449, 0.195327, 0.0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'])
df['End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Date'])

relevant_df = df[df['Relevant']]

date_range = pd.date_range(start= relevant_df['Start_Date'].min(), 
                           end =relevant_df['Start_Date'].max() ,freq = 'h')
print(date_range.to_series())

date_range_length = len(date_range)


rows = np.repeat(np.arange(len(relevant_df)), len(date_range))
cols = np.tile(np.arange(len(date_range)), len(relevant_df))
relevant_volume_data =   relevant_df['Volume'].values.repeat(len(date_range))

start_indices = np.searchsorted(date_range, relevant_df['Start_Date'].values)
end_indices = np.searchsorted(date_range, relevant_df['End_Date'].values)

mask = (cols >= start_indices[rows]) & (cols < end_indices[rows])
rows_masked,cols_masked,relevant_volume_data_masked = rows[mask], cols[mask], relevant_volume_data[mask]

csr_sparse_matrix = csr_matrix( (relevant_volume_data_masked, (rows_masked,cols_masked)),
shape =  (len(relevant_df), len(date_range) )
)           
summed_volumes = np.array(csr_sparse_matrix.sum(axis=0)).flatten()
res = pd.Series(summed_volumes,index = date_range)

